# Add something to a C# COM server and use it from C++ without recompiling

Tags: c#, c++, com-interop, tlb

Let's assume

> - I'm working for company A and I provide a C# DLL called `managed.dll` which is COM visible. I provide as well the TLB file called `managed.tlb`.
> - a company B is using my `managed.dll` in a C++ EXE called `unmanaged.exe`.
> - a customer C has to get the `managed.dll` from my company A and the `unmanaged.exe` from company B. The reason for that is that company B is not allowed to redistribute the `managed.dll` from company A.

Now let's assume I add a method or property to one of my classes in my `managed.dll`. Then the `unmanaged.exe` from company B is broken. Company B has to recompile it with the newer tlb-file.

How can I avoid that company B has to recompile their `unmanaged.exe` when I add something to my `managed.dll`?

The reason why I'm asking is

> - I've no control when company B is recompiling or releasing their `unmanaged.exe`. Even if I provide my `managed.dll` to company B every time I've added something.
> - I've no control which versions of the `managed.dll` and `unmanaged.exe` the customer C is using.
> - company B would like to claim that their `unmanaged.exe` V1.0 is working with my `managed.dll` V1.0 or **newer**.

How can we achieve that?

The source code of my `managed.dll` looks like that:

```
[Guid("852e5991-ddcc-56dd-8e13-90dcaf11ebe5")]
[ComVisible(true)]
public interface ITestA
{
    string DummyString();
    int DummyInt();
}

[Guid("41916928-6bea-43de-bedb-318df340e7b8")]
[ComVisible(true)]
[ComDefaultInterface(typeof(ITestA))]
public class TestA : ITestA
{
    public string DummyString() { return "Dummy"; }
    public int DummyInt() { return 123; }
}
```

The tlb-file is generated with `RegAsm.exe managed.dll /tlb /codebase`.

The source code of the `unmanaged.exe` looks like that:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#import "managed.tlb"
using namespace std;
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    HRESULT hr = CoInitialize(NULL); // Init COM
    IClassAPtr pClassA(__uuidof(ClassA));
    // and so on ...
}
```

Regards Wollmich

Comment: Changing the binary layout (signatures, add/remove methods, etc.) of a published IUnknown interface is kinda forbidden. You must provide new interfaces (like ITestA2, ITestA3, etc.). Or you could propose an Automation (late binding/IDispatch) interface instead of relying on IUnknown derivates. But it's somehow more work on the C++ side.

Comment: @Simon Mourier: Is this described somewhere in MSDN? Or do you have a reference which says that I've to provide a new Interface (ITestA2) if I want to add new methods?

Comment: @Wollmich: It's one of those "It's so obvious we don't need to state it" things. Each interface has a Globally Unique ID (GUID). Obviously, that only makes sense if the GUID identifies something that's indeed unique. Since you define two interfaces (old and new), you better have two ID's.

Comment: COM interfaces are immutable. This is explicitly documented here for example, but it's fairly logical: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms688484.aspx

Comment: @Simon Mourier: Thanks for the link. I can understand that an instance of an interface implementation is actually a pointer to an array of pointers to methods. But then I should be able to add new methods at the end of the ITestA interface. I've tested that and it's working as long I'm adding new methods at the end and not in the middle. But I guess that is still kinda forbidden, right?

Comment: yes, you're basically playing with the devil :-) a COM IUnknown interface is a binary contract. Once it's published outside of your dev environment, it's like cast in stone.

Comment: Ok thanks, I will go for the ITestA2 approach ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that I've to provide new interfaces (like ITestA2, ITestA3, etc.) if I want to add new methods or properties to my `managed.dll`.

So the source code of the `managed.dll` could be extended like that:

```
[Guid("5ff6c41a-6e4c-4d96-8e5e-72a560715b56")]
[ComVisible(true)]
public interface ITestA2
{
    string DummyString();
    int DummyInt();
    bool DummyBool(); // new method
}

[Guid("d5b8f4b5-d33f-4e7d-866c-ef0844216a3a")]
[ComVisible(true)]
[ComDefaultInterface(typeof(ITestA2))]
public class TestA2 : TestA, ITestA2
{
    public bool DummyBool() { return true; }
}
```

Remarks for .NET

> In COM interfaces can inherit from one another.  However the .NET implementation that exposes the .NET interface to COM does not support inheritance.  Therefore you must replicate any interface members in a base interface to the derived interface.

see [COM Interop: Base class properties not exposed to COM](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/7313191a-10db-4a16-9cdd-de9fb80b378a/com-interop-base-class-properties-not-exposed-to-com?forum=csharpgeneral).

Answer (score 2):

There's a reason Microsoft defined `IHTMLEventObj6`. That's the 5th incremental update of `IHTMLEventObj`. You'll need to do the same: `ITestA2` will need to inherit `ITestA` and add extra methods.